# Set firefox and chrome driver for selenium in java?

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing a problem with selenium web driver in java, it says that "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property" you can see it below, but I have set everything as usual I do.

[image: here]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the execution flow.

You see, you get the exception because you create `FirefoxDriver` first and THEN you set the property. It should be in reverse order.

First, set property and THEN initialize `WebDriver`:

```
public class EntryPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/executable.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows:
1. Try replacing "/" with "\" on your path.
2. If the previous step did not work, try running Intellij as an admin. The program might not have the right permissions to execute anything on that folder.